# How do I provide a fallback for placeholder attribute of input type password?

Tags: jquery, html, browser

I am  using the html5 placeholder attribute to show the default value in a login form. I am providing a kind of fallback support for IE browsers, but this doesn't work perfectly for password field. Is there a way to have password  field show some thing for placeholder  in IE.

**http://jsfiddle.net/8MTWx/**

EDIT:

Also how do I fix

```
$(this).attr("value",$(this).html);
```

because when the users left the field blank, it doesn't show them anyhting. i used

```
$(this).attr("value","username");
```

but then when they blur the value entered gets replaced by username which is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pass').focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() === ''){
        $(this).val('Password');
    }
});
```

Edit: if you want to mimic the placeholder effect for a password field, the least obtrusive way to do it would be to add a background image with the text 'password' `onBlur` like so:

```
$('#pass').focus(function(){
    $(this).val('').css('backgroundImage','');
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() === ''){
        $(this).css('backgroundImage','url(path/to/image)');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Mike does the above work for your original question? Can you please elaborate on your edit? You can use the above code for the `username` field as well, adjusting the value text accordingly of course.

Comment: No, not at all, $(this).val('Password'); will put ******** instead of password

Comment: @Mike That's because it's an `input type="password"`. You can't get around that unless you want to change the `input type` from `text` to `password` onClick. Which is not advised.

Comment: do you mean that there is no fallback for placeholder for password field

Comment: Not an unobtrusive one as far as I know. Actually.. you could use a background image onBlur.

Comment: I have used this plugin in the past with pretty good results: https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder. It also supports password types.